# Is SQL Azure a relational database?

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I don't really get this. Maybe it's a dumb question.

Is SQL Azure a relational db or it acts just like it?

Using ADO.NET and LINQ I've created a relational or non-relational database?

(I know these questions sound weird......!)

**EDIT:**

Ok, with one of the answers I've understood an important thing and I can know explain better my question.

i.e.: I've created a *non-relational* db for my app. Publishing it on Azure and loading on SQL Azure the database will the db be relational or not?

I think it will still be non-relational for the missing of primary keys and foreign keys. Will I get any errors?

So which is the utility of the Table Storage service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, SQL Azure is a relational database management system. The difference between SQL Azure and traditional MS SQL Server is that SQL Azure is designed to be run with high redundancy (i.e. multiple instances).

Comment: I think you meant to say, "SQL Azure is a relational database management system".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, SQL Azure is fully relational cloud database solution.

"Microsoft SQL Azure Database is a cloud-based relational database platform built on SQL Server technologies." extracted from Introducing SQL Azure Database http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336230.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try google?  First result for "is sql azure relational":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336230.aspx

*Microsoft SQL Azure Database is a cloud-based relational database platform built on SQL Server technologies*

Comment: Obviously I've tried but a Professor gave me a "false" hint telling me the contrary and keeping looking on google I've found different opinions.

What about the other question?

Comment: "Using ADO.NET and LINQ I've created a relational or non-relational database?" is not a question.  (It depends: did you create a relational one or a non-relational one?  ADO.NET/LINQ let you do either)

Comment: SQL Azure is an RDMS, i.e. it can 'do' relational databases.  If you have tables with PKs and FKs, you have a relational database.  If you put it on Azure, it's still relational.  If you have a DB without PKs and FKs, it's not relational.  You can put it on an RDMS, like Azure, but it won't magically become relational.

Comment: Finally, Table Storage Service is a non-relational DB store as per http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/

Answer (score 1):

We should probably distinguish between a Relational Database Management System RDBMS and a relational database.

SQL Server and SQL Azure are RDBMS but you can create databases that are not relational because they do not have the requisite keys, etc.

Using the features of a RDBMS helps to keep your data secure and maintain the integrity of that data. If you do not use these features, you have to rely on your application program (which presumably you have written)

A properly normalized database will eliminate orphan records and will not allow a certain amount of invalid data, regardless of the client/application you are using.

Here are Codd's rules numbered 0 thru 13. I don't believe that any commercially available RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) implements all of them, but usually several are implemented.

[Codd's 12 rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules)

A careful read of this may also be helpful
[Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: +1 for distinguishing between 'DBMS' and 'database'. However, I take issue with you for failing to distinguish between 'SQL DBMS' and 'truly relational DBMS`.

Answer (score 1):

First, the term 'database' refers to the collection of data whereas the 'term database management system' ('DBMS') refers to the software system managing the data. I think your question should be framed

> Can a SQL DBMS (such as Azure) be considered a relational DBMS?

Here's the history in a nutshell: Codd invents the relational model. Various implementations appear. SQL becomes the only implementation to be widely adopted but takes a long time to become relationally complete as regards Codd's definition of that term, by which time it had included features (which, thanks to the shackles of compatibility, can never be expunged) that are not faithful to the relational model, some of which were proposed by Codd but later abandoned (e.g. primary key, nulls, etc) but others simply from an apparent misunderstanding of the model (e.g. duplicate rows, reliance on column ordering, etc). The SQL Standard has always purposely avoided the word 'relation' and its derivatives but the same cannot be said of the vendors of SQL products.

I think the simple answer is that Entry Level SQL-92 Standard (hence all subsequent iterations of the Standard) is considered relationally complete as regards Codd's definition of that term but is not considered to be truly relational as regards current relational theory. However, determining whether a SQL product truly implements Entry Level SQL-92 is itself subjective: can we rely on a vendor's declaration of compliance.

I think the line of enquiry your teacher is encouraging you to take is to test the hypothesis that SQL Standards and products include features that are not faithful to the relational model. A good source of information on this may be found in Chris Date's recent book [SQL and Relational Theory: How to Accurate SQL Code (2009)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=406_pJtiJ6sC&printsec=frontcover).

Answer (score 0):

To your comment: "Professor gave me a "false" hint telling me the contrary" <- while SQL Azure is a relational DBMS like everyone else said. What your professor might have want you to refer is this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbiyikoglu/archive/2011/03/03/nosql-genes-in-sql-azure-federations.aspx

Answer (score -1):

ADO.NET and LINQ can create databases (schemas) that are relational as well as those that are not relational.

A relational database must have tables with primary keys and tables with foreign keys that reference the primary keys in the first tables.

All tables should have primary keys in order for the database to be truly relational.

You should do some research on normalization. Check into Codd's rules (Edgar F. Codd). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_F._Codd

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful. Maybe I really didn't get well the differences between the two. Please check the edit on the question.

Comment: -1 Your description of the relational model is wholly incorrect.